# ¿Como puedo ingresar datos sin repetir?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, netbeans

[image]
Buenas, una consulta... estoy en NetBeans y MySQL y necesito poder ingresar datos a mi tabla solo si no se ha ingresado antes el nombre, como podria llegar a hacerlo, ya trate pero me sale errores y no se en que estoy fallando, aqui solo muestro el codigo para solo ingresar valores a una base de hecha en phpMyAdmin

Comment: Hola Alvaro, te recomiendo que el código lo pegues como texto y que incluyas una etiqueta con el lenguajes que utilizas para los comandos mysql.

Comment: Buenas Alvaro, el campo nomPostre es clave de la tabla?

Comment: no, la clave es un auto-incrementable,la tabla solo consta de su id y el nombre, que seria nomPostre, perdon si no soy muy claro no conozco sobre base de datos... y tengo que evitar que se repita por el nombre ingresado

Comment: Para evitar valores repetidos, aunque controles también en la lógica del programa (en el código), no debes delegar esa función tan fundamental a la lógica, sino que la columna debería tener [una restricción `UNIQUE`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/). De ese modo, cuando se intente insertar un dato repetido el manejador de base de datos lo impedirá, hayas hecho o no un control por código. Con un `ALTER TABLE` puedes agregar dicha restricción, pero primero debes revisar que no hay filas con datos repetidos en esa columna.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es que antes de introducir la variable hagas la consulta para sacar el nombre que quieres adjuntar. Sería algo así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postres WHERE nomPostre = 'nombre_que_vas_a_insertar'
```

Si esa consulta te devuelve 0, puedes insertar con confianza el nuevo dato:

```
INSERT INTO postres(nomPostre) VALUES('nombre_que_vas_a_insertar');
```